# mount of SD card in C program

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

My environment: Petalinux on Xilinx/Zynq Soc

I am trying to mount microSD card.
I confirmed that following code works to mount SD under root login.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ret;
    ret = system("mkdir /media/card");
    printf("%d\n", ret);

    ret = system("mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/card");
    if (ret == 0) {
        printf("sd mounted to /media/card\n");
    } else {
        printf("sd mount : fail\n");
    }
}
```

Is this a normal way to mount SD card in linux C program?
Or are there any special systemcall/API used in C program to mount SD?

Comment: No need for `system()`, just use `mount(2)` system call (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mounting filesystems is done with the [mount(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount) system call.  That's what the `mount` program (that you're calling via `system`) actually does.

The normal way to mount a filesystem from a C program is to use the system call.  Forking off a separate process to run a shell command (i.e. using the `system` function) is inefficient and prone to bugs (such as shell-injection security vulnerabilities), and gives you less control.  The same goes for calling the `mkdir` program; just use the [mkdir(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir) system call instead.  (Your program above is essentially a shell script written in C, which is silly.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Instead of system(), I will use mount(2) and mkdir(2). I appreciate it.